# Simple asynchronous task with asyncio

Tags: python, asynchronous, python-asyncio

I have a function that takes a lot of time to run, but actually has returns no program relevant value -- it simply does some IO / plotting to store current progress.

I would like to asynchronously call it, and have found the newly core'd asyncio library. My main function then looks something like

```
async def doStuff(input):
    plt.figure()
    plt.plot(input)
    plt.savefig('foobar.pdf')
```

However, it's unclear to me how to exactly call that. All examples I've seen do a variant on

```
loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
# Blocking call which returns when the hello_world() coroutine is done
loop.run_until_complete(doStuff()
```

but actually, I just need a single call (not a loop), and explicitely do not want to wait ever for it to finish. What's the most trivial implementation of that in the `asyncio` framework?

Comment: `asyncio` is for coordinating multiple cooperatively multitasking functions. The thread can only run one function at a time, but with `async`/`await` you can suspend one function and let another run; the event loop coordinates when to resume which function. This does not appear to be what you're after, you want to have code run on a different thread entirely *in parallel* with other code.

Comment: Definitely wrong marked. OP doesn't seem to understand how `asyncio` works at all. He need more information than just "wrap event loop in a background thread." First, there is no asynchronous disk IO support in Linux. Second, this task can be done by just launching a background thread without using `asyncio`.